# Any alternative way to evaluate $ \int\frac{1}{\sin x + \sec x } \, dx $ ??

Tags: integration

$$
\int\frac{1}{\sin x + \sec x }  \, dx
$$

1st method involves converting to sin x and cos x then multiplying and dividing by 2 and finally separating the integrands .

2nd one involves rationalising the denominator and then separating the integrands.

it is hard to think of both the approaches during an exam .

Any other easy alternative anyone has which can be easily thought of ?

please tell of high school level only .

Comment: Are you [sure](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(sin+x%2B+sec+x)+dx) this is the question?

Comment: This would not be an appropriate question to ask on an exam.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584604/evaluate-int-frac1-sin-x-sec-x-dx

Comment: @RobertIsrael https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584604/evaluate-int-frac1-sin-x-sec-x-dx Lab Bhattacharjee has given a very nice answer here

Comment: @RobertIsrael I know but they give it in exams . they are too harsh

Comment: And to the ones saying it is duplicate , I asked for alternates .

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, this is a surprising problem.

Any way, using the tangent half-angle substitution, you will end with
$$I=\int\frac{2t^2-2}{t^4-2 t^3+2 t^2+2 t+1 }\,dt$$ The denominator does not show real roots but let us call them $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$ making
$$I=\int\frac{2t^2-2}{(t-r_1)(t-r_2)(t-r_3)(t-r_4)}\,dt$$ and use partial fraction decomposition to arrive to something looking like
$$I=\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{a_i}{t-r_ i}\,dt=\sum_{i=1}^4 a_i\log(t-r_i)$$

I wish a lot of fun to those who would like to do it.

Answer (score 1):

With abbrevations $c=\cos x$ and $s=\sin x$, we have

$$\int{dx\over\sin x+\sec x}=\int{c\,dx\over1+sc}=\int{c(1-sc)\,dx\over1-s^2c^2}=\int{ds\over1-s^2(1-s^2)}+\int{c^2\,dc\over1-(1-c^2)c^2}$$

At this point, the problem becomes a pair of partial fractions.